# llenar un combobox con consulta sql vb6

Tags: sql, sql-server, combobox, vb6, vba

Estoy intentando llenar un combobox desde una consulta en sql server pero no muestra nada..

parte del codigo es:

```
Private Sub cmdTipoPago_Change()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Cnn.Open
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "SELECT ClaveDeMetodoDePago, MetodoDePago FROM CatalogoDeFormaDePago", Cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Combo1.Text = "[Seleccione el tipo de pago]"
Do Until rs.EOF
Combo1.Additem rs!MetodoDePago
Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = rs.Collect("ClaveDeMetodoDePago")

rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

en el modulo general tengo la conexion al servidor.

Lo mas curiosos es que es en visual basic 6 (no lo decidi yo asi estaba desde que llegue, empece a trabajar en C# el nuevo sistema pero tengo que agregar esta funcion

Al final logre anexarlo

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SELECT ClaveDeMetodoDePago, MetodoDePago FROM CatalogoDeFormaDePago"

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sql, Cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

cmdTipoPago.Text = "[Seleccione la forma de pago]"
Do Until rs.EOF
cmdTipoPago.Additem rs!MetodoDePago
cmdTipoPago.ItemData(cmdTipoPago.NewIndex) = rs.Collect("ClaveDeMetodoDePago")
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre hacerlo con esta parte del codigo.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SELECT ClaveDeMetodoDePago, MetodoDePago FROM CatalogoDeFormaDePago"

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open sql, Cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

cmdTipoPago.Text = "[Seleccione la forma de pago]"
Do Until rs.EOF
cmdTipoPago.Additem rs!MetodoDePago
cmdTipoPago.ItemData(cmdTipoPago.NewIndex) = rs.Collect("ClaveDeMetodoDePago")
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```